# Problema com envio do phpmailer no servidor

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Gente, isso pode ser um problema simples ou complicado, só sei que não consigo resolver.

Fiz milhares de pesquisas em tópicos da hospedagem, aqui do Stack, mas mesmo assim não funciona, então não sei se o problema está nos arquivos do phpmailer, ou nas configurações no servidor

No meu servidor local (xampp) as coisas funcionam normalmente, o php mailer envia emails certinho para o gmail.
Já no servidor da hospedagem nada funciona. O que aparece de mensagem de erro é a seguinte:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '--' (T_DEC) in /home3/centroed/public_html/site/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php on line 4046
```

esse erro só é apresentado no servidor "real" e o arquivo nem mexi, pois veio direto do GitHub

Não é versão do php (7.2)

as configurações de apps menos seguros do google já estão ativadas

as informações de email e senha do `phpmailer` estão corretas

`openssl` já está habilitado

e o único detalhe é o `php.ini` que não existe no servidor e precisei criar um próprio. Não sei se o problema está no `php.ini` ou outro lugar, só sei que tentei várias coisas e a maioria não funciona... Alguma ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: Alterou a versão do PHP pra uma inferior pra ver se o erro persiste?

Comment: alterei para a 5.5 e continua :/

Comment: estava 7.0 e já aparecia

Comment: Hmmmm, você usa CPANEL no servidor? Confere se o problema não está no ID priority mail, onde você  precisa dar permissão para uso externo do serviço mail (smtp). E qual versionamento do phpmailer você  usa? Tenho uma versão que funciona lindo, talvez trocar a versão do phpmailer resolve o problema.

Comment: uso o cpanel sim. Onde exatamente fica o ID priority? o phpmailer é o 5.2 pq segundo o github é uma versão estável, então escolhi essa. Trocar a versão para uma posterior (a ultima é a 6.0) vai implicar em mudar oq?

Comment: Então, a que tenho aqui funciona em qualquer ambiente, e é estável pra qualquer versão PHP acima de 5.X se quiser envio ela pra você pra que você possa testá-la. Mas como te envio?

Comment: so me explica certinho o que precisa ser feito

Comment: Me dá uns 10 min que te envio, estou finalizando um CODE.

Comment: haha ok, não esquce de por o ponto e vírgula ; e fechar a chaves } (rs)

Comment: rsrs suave, fica tranquilo, esta versão não tem erro.